# How do I tell NEXUS to use a custom truststore

Tags: java, ssl, nexus, docker-swarm

In our company network, our servers are using self signed certificates. I have a NEXUS Repository Manager service running on a docker swarm and I want to setup LDAP authentication. But as my LDAP server also uses a self signed certificate, my NEXUS service fails to connect. I get the following error:

```
There is an error communicating with the server. Failed to connect to Ldap Server: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found<br/><br/>Nexus returned an error: ERROR 400: Bad Request
```

When I searched fo a solution, I found this article in the sonatype NEXUS documentation: https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager2/secure-socket-layer-ssl/managing-outbound-ssl-certificates#ManagingOutboundSSLCertificates-ConfiguringNexusRepositoryManagerWithaCustomTruststore

I tried to follow this article. First I customized the ${NEXUS_HOME}/bin/jws/conf/wrapper.conf file (see number 4 and 5):

```java
# Additional JVM parameters (tune if needed, but match the sequence of numbers!)
wrapper.java.additional.1=-Djava.io.tmpdir=./tmp
wrapper.java.additional.2=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
wrapper.java.additional.3=-Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.protocol="plain ssl"
wrapper.java.additional.4=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/usr/secrets/truststore.jks
wrapper.java.additional.5=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
```

After the modification, I started NEXUS with the provided start script (see my Dockerfile for adding modified wrapper.conf and starting application):

```sh
[...]
COPY ./wrapper.conf /opt/sonatype/nexus/bin/jws/conf/wrapper.conf

RUN chown -R -L nexus.nexus ${NEXUS_HOME}
RUN chown -R nexus.nexus ${SONATYPE_WORK}

USER nexus
WORKDIR ${NEXUS_HOME}

CMD ${NEXUS_HOME}/bin/nexus console
```

I start my nexus service using a compose yml file and call

```
docker stack deploy --compose-file /path/to/my/nexus.yml nexus
```

Then I check on which of my swarm nodes the container is running and attach to it with

```
docker exec -ti <containername> bash
```

I checked that my modified wrapper.conf is in the container -> OK
Then I checked the java process of NEXUS with `ps -ef | grep java` -> My jvm properties `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore`and  `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword` are not visible:

Output of `ps -ef | grep java`:

```
nexus       76    74  0 11:29 ?        00:01:22 java -Djava.io.tmpdir=./tmp -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.protocol=plain ssl -Xms256m -Xmx768m -Djava.library.path=bin/jsw/lib -classpath bin/jsw/lib/wrapper-3.2.3.jar:./lib/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:./lib/jetty-servlet-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:./lib/logback-access-1.2.3.jar:./lib/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar:./lib/jetty-webapp-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:./lib/javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar:./lib/metrics-jetty-2.2.0.jar:./lib/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar:./lib/jetty-jmx-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:./lib/jetty-client-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:./lib/jetty-deploy-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:./lib/jetty-io-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:./lib/jetty-util-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:./lib/nexus-bootstrap-2.14.14-01.jar:./lib/jetty-security-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:./lib/plexus-interpolation-1.16.jar:./lib/jetty-xml-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:./lib/logback-core-1.2.3.jar:./lib/jetty-http-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:./lib/jetty-continuation-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:./lib/metrics-logback-2.2.0.jar:./lib/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:./lib/jetty-rewrite-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:./lib/jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:./conf/ -Dwrapper.key=zAxEtY8vJ5V7ACyi -Dwrapper.port=32000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.min=31000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.max=31999 -Dwrapper.pid=74 -Dwrapper.version=3.2.3 -Dwrapper.native_library=wrapper -Dwrapper.cpu.timeout=10 -Dwrapper.jvmid=1 org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jsw.JswLauncher ./conf/jetty.xml ./conf/jetty-requestlog.xml
```

I can see there the 3 jvm parameters
`-Djava.io.tmpdir=./tmp`, `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` and `-Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.protocol="plain ssl"` from `wrapper.conf` but not my two new ones.

Can anyone please have a look at this and give me some advice?

Answer (score 0):

For those who may have the same question sometimes:
I did not really figure out, why my custom properties from wrapper.conf are ignored, but I found a workaround:

I added the certificate from my custom truststore to the one of the default java installation using `keytool`